# Is there any way to obtain a Rhyperior without trading?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

Is it possible to get a Rhyperior without trading to anyone in Pokémon Diamond or Pearl? I am playing on an emulator and will not have the possibility to trade to anyone. I would like not to use cheats if possible.

Comment: It might be worth noting that some emulators actually do allow you to trade. I have used this functionality in the past to trade with another emulator user on the same local network.

Comment: If you were playing on an emulator, you may have to use an NTEVO ROM (No Trade Evolution). I managed to evolve my Scyther and Electabuzz using this kind of ROM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rhyperior_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Game_locations) it is only available in Diamond and Pearl by evolving Rhydon. For that, you need to trade it, so I think you are out of luck, unfortunately.

Comment: this is the answer I feared, I thought some pokemon pro would have a miracle... cheats it will be I guess but it feels like less accomplishment to cheat...

Comment: You can always"punish" yourself when cheating to feel better. I do not know how far you can go with the emulator, but you could say "everytime I am *trading* it costs me 500k pokédollars", you would do the evolution and remove 500k from your money. In that way you do not have to feel bad @JohnnyBgud